# GO live visual code

Tags: php, post, visual

Buenas tardes es una consulta, tengo un proyecto en go live, estoy haciendo peticiones POST y no me permite, el go live lo uso por una IA q obtiene los datos en video en tiempo real por eso requiero el go life, pero investigando no acepta peticiones POST, alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask]. Si deseas una opinión puedes obtener reputación y preguntar en [chat], saludos.